# Google Analytics - _trackEvent for multiple profiles

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

We're trying to track click events for a main Google Analytics profile and a secondary profile. Page views are correctly being registered for both profiles.

The problem is that click events are only being registered for the main profile, not the secondary profile. We've waited more than 24 hours to see if there was a delay in the secondary account click events being registered in GA but no joy. (It typically takes about 15 mins for the click events to be registered correctly for the main profile). Appreciate it if anybody can spot what the problem is in the code below. Many thanks

```
var _gaq = _gaq || []; 

var mainAccount = 'UA-1234567-1';
var secondaryAccount = 'UA-1234567-2';

_gaq.push(  ['_setAccount', mainAccount], 
            ['_trackPageview'],
            ['b._setAccount', secondaryAccount], 
            ['b._trackPageview']);

(function(){
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

jQuery(document).ready(function()
    { 
        jQuery('.home-bottom-right a').click(function(){
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Homepage', 'click', 'Home_bottom_right'],['b._trackEvent', 'Homepage', 'click', 'Home_bottom_right']);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try is make the click tracking line into 2 lines

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Homepage', 'click', 'Home_bottom_right']);
_gaq.push(['b._trackEvent', 'Homepage', 'click', 'Home_bottom_right']);
```

On the guide page provided by google, they always track one event per push. So give that a try and maybe it will work, the code looks good other than that. Maybe b isn't set up correctly

Comment: Its fine to push multiple actions in one push statement.

Comment: @ddlshack most likely, but everything else looks good, why not give it a try, it only takes a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

If the click you're tracking is opening a new page in the current window, it's likely that the  second `_trackEvent` tracking pixel request may not have completed before leaving the current page.

I use variations of the following code to add a 150 millisecond delay for links that open in the same window:

```
jQuery('.home-bottom-right a').click(function(e){
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Homepage', 'click', 'Home_bottom_right'],['b._trackEvent', 'Homepage', 'click', 'Home_bottom_right']);
  if (this.target != '_blank') {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = this.href;
    setTimeout('location.href = "' + url + '"', 150);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to mike's answer, you can test the length of the _gaq array to see if analytics has finished processing all objects:

```
jQuery('.home-bottom-right a').click(function(e){
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Homepage', 'click', 'Home_bottom_right'],['b._trackEvent', 'Homepage', 'click', 'Home_bottom_right']);
    if (this.target !== '_blank') {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = this.href;
        (function() {
            if (typeof _gaq.length == "undefined" || _gaq.length == 0) {
                location.href = url;
            } else {
                setTimeout(arguments.callee, 0);
            }
        })();
    }
});
```

Comment: Cool... I didn't know that about the _gaq array! Another approach would be to push a function onto the _gaq array, which (assuming the function is the last element of the array) could open the new page. One thing I'm not sure of is even though _gaq processing has completed, the tracking pixel request may not have, so you could still loose events...